# k8s helm install bitnami/postgresql is not running, could not access file "repmgr"

Tags: postgresql

Firt, i apply `storageclass, pv, pvc`
`pvc(data-icas-postgres-postgresql)` Status is Bound

```
kind: StorageClass apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1 metadata: name: icas-pgsql-storage namespace: icas-pgsql reclaimPolicy: Retain provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner volumeBindingMode: Immediate allowVolumeExpansion: true mountOptions: \- debug` \


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
name: data-icas-postgres-postgresql-pv
namespace: icas-pgsql
spec:
storageClassName: icas-pgsql-storage
capacity:
storage: 5Gi
accessModes:
- ReadWriteMany
hostPath:
path: "/bitnami/postgresql"

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: data-icas-postgres-postgresql
namespace: icas-pgsql
spec:
storageClassName: icas-pgsql-storage
accessModes:
- ReadWriteMany
resources:
requests:
storage: 5Gi
```

and install bitnami/postgresql using helm

```
helm install icas-postgres icas-repo/postgresql \ --set global.storageClass="icas-pgsql-storage" \ --set primary.persistence.existingClaim="data-icas-postgres-postgresql" \ --set global.postgresql.auth.postgresPassword="MYPASSWD" \ --set global.postgresql.auth.username=postgresl \ --set global.postgresql.auth.password="MYPASSWD" \ --set global.postgresql.auth.database=postgres \ --set image.tag="15.2.0-debian-11-r0" \ --set volumePermissions.enabled=true \ --set image.debug=true \ -n icas-pgsql
```

but Pod is not ready
it's pod's logs

```
Defaulted container "postgresql" out of: postgresql, init-chmod-data (init)
postgresql 07:23:30.69
postgresql 07:23:30.70 Welcome to the Bitnami postgresql container
postgresql 07:23:30.70 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
postgresql 07:23:30.70 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
postgresql 07:23:30.70
postgresql 07:23:30.71 DEBUG ==\> Configuring libnss_wrapper...
postgresql 07:23:30.73 INFO  ==\> \*\* Starting PostgreSQL setup \*\*
postgresql 07:23:30.76 INFO  ==\> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL\_\* env vars..
postgresql 07:23:30.77 INFO  ==\> Loading custom pre-init scripts...
postgresql 07:23:30.78 INFO  ==\> Initializing PostgreSQL database...
postgresql 07:23:30.79 DEBUG ==\> Copying files from /bitnami/postgresql/conf to /opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf
postgresql 07:23:30.79 INFO  ==\> Custom configuration /opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/postgresql.conf detected
postgresql 07:23:30.80 INFO  ==\> Custom configuration /opt/bitnami/postgresql/conf/pg_hba.conf detected
postgresql 07:23:30.80 DEBUG ==\> Ensuring expected directories/files exist...
postgresql 07:23:30.85 INFO  ==\> Deploying PostgreSQL with persisted data...
postgresql 07:23:30.85 INFO  ==\> Loading custom scripts...
postgresql 07:23:30.87 INFO  ==\> \*\* PostgreSQL setup finished! \*\*

postgresql 07:23:30.89 INFO  ==\> \*\* Starting PostgreSQL \*\*
2023-10-23 07:23:30.919 GMT \[1\] FATAL:  could not access file "repmgr": No such file or directory
2023-10-23 07:23:30.919 GMT \[1\] LOG:  database system is shut down\
```

i try add helm set option

```
\--set global.storageClass="icas-pgsql-storage" \ \--set primary.persistence.existingClaim="data-icas-postgres-postgresql" \ \--set volumePermissions.enabled=true \\
```

and `delete, apply storageclass, pv, pvc`